# Pass values using JSON via Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I am beginner on `JSON`. In my web application I am trying convert the `table` values into `JSON` and pass to another page using `ajax call`.

Below is my `ajax query` which I tried to convert the `table values` and pass to `prescription.php` page to save the records. There are two different separate `java script variables` which need to sent to the above page.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#submit', function () {
        var getapt = $('#getapt').val();  
        var getpid = $('#getpid').val();  

        var ids={ 
            'getapt': getapt,
            'getpid': getpid,
        }

        var modess = $('#rows tr').map(function() {
            let $tr = $(this);

            return [{ 
                "medname": $(this).find('.med_name').val(),
                "morning": $(this).find('.morning').val(),
                "noon": $(this).find('.noon').val(),
                "night": $(this).find('.night').val(),
            }]

            console.log(modess);
        });

        var ids = JSON.stringify(ids);
        var medical = JSON.stringify(modess);


        $.ajax({
            url: "adminquery/prescription.php", // Url to which the request is send
            type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
            data:{
                index1: medical, 
                index2: ids
            },
            dataType:'json',             
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my prescription.php page

```
<?php    
session_start();
require_once "../auth/dbconnection.php";

// if (isset(json_decode($_POST["data"])) {
$medical = json_decode($_POST["data"]);

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,"INSERT INTO prescription (apt_id,user_id,p_id, med_records,date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")){
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $user_id);
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
// }else{
//     echo "now records";
// }

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
?>
```

Here is my `HTML` codes.

```
    <form method="post" id="prescriptionn" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered mb-0" id="medical">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Medicine Name</th>
                        <th>Morning</th>
                        <th>Noon</th>
                        <th>Night</th>

  <th> <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"> 
+ </button>  </th>

                    </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="rows"> 
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                 <br><br>
         <div align="center">
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['apt_id'] ?>" id="getapt" 
 name="getapt" class="btn btn-primary">

      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['p_id'] ?>" id="getpid" name="getpid" class="btn btn-primary">


      <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enter Prescription">

                   </div>
                   </div>
                   </form>
```

But nothing happen when I submit the button. Please give me some suggestions to improve my code may highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the JS executed? Can you debug this. Would be helpful have the HTML code aswell

Comment: You are decoding your json in php, but never using `$medical` again?

Comment: @davidev Yes `JS` is executed.

Comment: Good. Thanks for the HTML code. Can you check wheather the php is called aswell - so if the AJAX call works. And why don't you need the $medical again in your PHP?

Comment: @davidev So then how to `decode` this `Json` data??/

Comment: You have 5 placeholders in your db-query, but you only bind one param. You also never execute your query at all, so your db-code won't actually _do_ anything.

Comment: And in your PHP, you should be able to get the data using: `$index1 = $_POST['index1']; $index2 = $_POST['index2'];`. jQuery accepts the data as an json object, but as default, it will still send it just like a normal form would send it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Any `decode` needed to convert into `PHP` variable?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson   `$index2 = $_POST['index2'];` it contains two `variables` to store two sepeate fields.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson when i was submitting, in developers tool it shows like this `e = {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Method show how to send HTML table data using jQuery Ajax and save in Database. Hope this will help.

```
function storeTblValuesSpecial(x)
{
var TableData = new Array();
$('#'+x+''+' tr').each(function(row, tr){
TableData[row]={

  "columOne" :$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
, "columTwo" : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
, "columThree" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()

}    
}); 
TableData.shift();  // first row will be empty - so remove
return TableData;
}


function storeTblValuesAjax(y) {
var TableData;
TableData = JSON.stringify(storeTblValuesSpecial(y));
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '../yourFile.php',
data: {
"pTableData" : TableData
},
success: function(msg){
alert('Success');
}
});
}

<table id="table1" class="table table-dark" border="1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">columOne</th>
         <th scope="col">columTwo</th>
         <th scope="col">columThree</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" class="btn-danger" id = "delete" onclick="storeTblValuesAjax('table1')" >Save Table</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**From PHP File once the Post Request Sent through Ajax Call**

```
<?php
session_start();

// Unescape the string values in the JSON array
$tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['pTableData']);

 // Decode the JSON array
$records = json_decode($tableData,TRUE);

$sizeOfArray =  sizeof($records);
for($test = 1; $test < $sizeOfArray; $test++)
{

$columOne= str_replace(",","",$records[$test]['columOne']);
$columTwo= str_replace(",","",$records[$test]['columTwo']);
$columThree= str_replace(",","",$records[$test]['columThree']);

/* From Here a general SQL Insert query , pass $columOne , $columTwo , $columThree as the insert values, the loop will continue until the entire table is saved */
}
```